# Regular simplex in projective space

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Is there a reference or a very short argument proving the following statement?

Let $C$ be a set consisting of $r$ points in the real projective space $\mathbb RP ^k$
with its usual round metric. Assume that the distances between all pairs of points in $C$ are the same. Assume further that  $r>k+1$. Then $r$ must be equal to $k+2$ and $C$ must be the image of the set of vertices of a regular simplex inscribed in the unit sphere.

Comment: Is it possible that you mean the sphere and not real projective space?

Comment: No, I really meant the projective space and am very surprised by the negative answer to my question. 

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Equidistant points in projective space correspond to equiangular lines in Euclidean space. The maximum number of equiangular lines in $\mathbb R^n$, $f(n)$ is a function which might not be as nice as you think, some computed values are in [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A002853). For example, your claim fails even in the case $k=2$ where you can take the six large diagonals of the icosahedron and get 6 equidistant points in $\mathbb RP^2$. An absolute upper bound is given by $f(n)\le \binom{n+1}{2}$ (attributed to Gerzon in "Equiangular lines" by Lemmens and Siedel, proved again later by Koornwinder in ["A note on the absolute bound for systems of lines"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B7GXJ-4D7KB2N-4W&_user=1010281&_coverDate=12%2F31%2F1976&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=search&_origin=search&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_acct=C000050264&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=1010281&md5=b0d4d826c10d0f60aa5f05cbe925cb71&searchtype=a) in both real and complex case).

Comment: Many thanks for the surprising answer.

Comment: The link to `sciencedirect.com` is broken, but the article can be found at [doi:10.1016/1385-7258(76)90060-3](https://doi.org/10.1016/1385-7258(76)90060-3) ([Zbl 0328.05020](https://zbmath.org/0328.05020)).